# Implementación de pila con doble puntero

Tags: c

tengo la definición de tipos siguiente:

```
typedef struct _pnodo {
float Elem; /* Elemento de la pila. */
struct _pnodo *Sig; /*Puntero al siguiente nodo*/
} tNodo;

typedef tNodo tPila;
```

Y tengo que realizar varias funciones para utilizar la pila, como por ejemplo:

```
tPila **AsignarMemoria(void);

int Apilar(tPila **p, float E);
```

Y otras muchas, la cuestión es que entiendo el funcionamiento de la pila, y creo que entendería esto en caso de ser sólo tPila * p, pero al aparecer ese doble puntero, no tengo ni idea de como tratarlo.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda. Saludos

Comment: "Doble puntero" solo significa que es un puntero normal, es decir, contiene una dirección de memoria. Pero lo que hay en esa dirección, en lugar de ser una estructura, es otro puntero. En este caso ese segundo puntero apunta a un `struct tPila`. La razón por la que se suele usar el  `**` es para pasar un puntero por referencia (por ejemplo porque la función tiene que cambiar el valor de ese puntero).

Comment: No veo claro en cambio por qué `AsignarMemoria()` habría de retornar un puntero a puntero ¿Seguro que es así ese caso? ¿Qué se supone que hace la función?

Comment: Si no tienes idea de como _tratarlo_, simplemente no lo _trates_, haz que la función devuelva un puntero a `tPila`.

Comment: Hola, tengo que usarlo aunque no lo entienda, porque no puedo cambiar la cabecera. Respecto de la función AsignarMemoria, debe devolver memoria para un puntero a *tPila.

Comment: El por qué el doble puntero ya esta en los comentarios... sobre todo el de @abulafia, ahora te pongo un ejemplo practico de por qué esto, crea una función que reciba por parámetro un puntero, y dentro de esa función asignale memoria dinamicamente a ese puntero, ahora por fuera de la función veras como el puntero que pasaste por parámetros a la función no guardo la dirección de memoria a la cual le acabaste de asignar.... bueno esto se soluciona con el doble puntero, es como pasar por referencia un puntero, si lo quieres ver de esa manera.

Answer (score 0):

NOTA: El código en la respuesta ha sido escrito sobre la marcha y puede no compilar o contener errores.

No existe motivo aparente para que la función `tPila **AsignarMemoria(void);` retorne un doble puntero.

Existen casos en los que sí se debe tratar con un doble puntero y el ejemplo más sencillo que se me ocurre es la liberación de la memoria:

```
// Liberar memoria toma un doble puntero para poder asignar un valor al puntero original
void LiberarMemoria(tPila **pp) {
    // Liberamos la memoria previamente alojada
    free(*pp);
    // Ahora podemos modificar el valor de 'p' en main porque hemos pasado un puntero a p.
    *pp = NULL;
}

// Esta función no podría modificar el argumento que se le pasa
void LiberarMemoriaErronea(tPila *p) {
    // La siguiente llamada liberaría la memoria a la que apunta 'p' en el main
    free(p);
    // Pero no podríamos modificar la dirección a la que apunta 'p' en el main porque el valor no se retornaría
    p = NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    // Alojamos memoria para una instancia de tPila con una función que devuelve un puntero simple...
    tPila *p = AsignarMemoria2();
    // Utilizamos la pila
    ...
    // Liberamos la pila
    LiberarMemoria(&p);
}
```

En caso de los requerimientos manden que `AsignarMemoria` retorne un doble puntero has de recordar que toda variable que crees de manera local desaparecerá al destruirse el entorno donde se ha creado por lo que tendrías que realizar un alojamiento de memoria para apuntar al segundo puntero:

```
// En la siguiente función hay un error...
tPila **AsignarMemoriaMal(void) {
    // Este puntero apuntará a la zona de memoria que devuelva malloc donde nosotros vamos a almacenar una estructura de tipo tPila.
    // Hay que saber que un puntero es un trozo de memoria donde en lugar de guardar un valor, guardamos una dirección.
    // Con la siguiente instrucción lo que hemos hecho ha sido reservar un trozo de memoria que será destruido al salir de esta función.
    // En ese trozo de memoria vamos a almacenar la dirección a la que queremos apuntar.
    tPila *p;
    // Ahora vamos a crear un puntero que apunte a otro puntero que apuntará a una pila.
    // De nuevo lo que está pasando, es que el compilador reservará otro trocito de memoria para guardar una dirección.
    // Este trocito de memoria también sera destruido al salir de esta función.
    tPila **pp
    // En la siguiente linea hacemos que malloc reserve memoria que no se destruirá.
    // Malloc devolverá la dirección de la memoria reservada y se asignará a p.
    // p ahora apunta a la memoria reservada.
    // p (no seguro) -> memoria_de_malloc (seguro)
    // Si hiciesemos un 'return p;' se copiaría lo que hay dentro de p, por lo que la nueva variable apuntaría a la dirección de la memoria segura.
    p = malloc(...);
    // El error reside en la siguiente linea, donde ahora hacemos que el puntero siga a memoria no segura.
    // pp (no seguro) -> p (no seguro) -> memoria_de_malloc (seguro)
    // Si hiciesemos un 'return pp;' se copiaría lo que hay dentro de pp, por lo que la nueva variable apuntaría a la dirección de p, que se destruirá en cuanto salgamos de la función.
    tPila **pp = &p;
    // Por lo que el siguiente return devolverá una posición de memoria que podría ser sobreescrita...
    return pp;
}
```

Comment: Hola, he desarrollado la función de la manera que me indicas, sólo he incluido el malloc, pero ¿así es errónea?. No se si hace lo que se espera, la verdad: tPila *p = malloc(sizeof(tNodo));

Comment: Así es erronea. Intentaré aclararlo mejor en la propia respuesta ya que creo que responder aquí sería demasiado difícil por la falta de caracteres.

Comment: No necesitas un _doble puntero_ para liberar memoria, a menos que quieras asignar su valor a `NULL` al momento de finalizar su ciclo de vida, fuera de eso, te ahorras el tener que cargar la dirección de memoria que aloja el puntero para poder liberar, es una instrucción, que puede tardar segundos en máquinas antiguas, sería bueno que lo agregaras a la respuesta, así se entiende la razón por la cual se puede usar así.

Comment: Si, en mi caso paso un puntero doble para poder asignar el valor `NULL` al puntero en el momento. Considero que es la manera de proceder porque en caso contrario sería necesario asignar ese valor justo después de ejecutar la función liberar memoria. Si hablamos de que la diferencia entre una alternativa y la otra son "unos segundos" por el motivo de que hay que hacer una asignación simple, no deberíamos estar usando C sino ensamblador dado que cada instrucción supone un tiempo de ejecución muy considerable.